# How to print a dictionary as key and count (if values is list) without for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary as follows

```
dic = {0: [1,2,3,4,5], 1:[7,4,6]}
```

While printing the dictionary as key and count, first updating the dictionary

```
for k, v in dic.items():
   dic[k] = len(v)

print(dic)

>>> {0:5, 1:3}
```

Is there a better way to do the above without for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean saying without iteration? If you don't want to use a `for` loop, you can use a map function:

```
d = dict(map(lambda kv: (kv[0], len(kv[1])), d.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If by no iteration you simply mean to do it without a `for` loop, you can map the dict values to the `len` function, zip them with the dict keys and pass the zipped key-value pairs to the dict constructor:

```
>>> d = {0: [1,2,3,4,5], 1:[7,4,6]}
>>> dict(zip(d, map(len, d.values())))
{0: 5, 1: 3}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not name a list 'list' or a dictionary 'dict', as this is a reserved word in python for the class that holds that data type.

You can do it neatly using dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
d = {0: [1,2,3,4,5], 1:[7,4,6]}
d = {i:len(j) for i,j in d.items()}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use:

```
print({k:len(dic[k]) for k in dic})
```

Output:

```
{0: 5, 1: 3}
```